# How to use max-width breakpoints in UnoCSS

Tags: unocss

I use `md:bg-pink` and it become like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TC3E.png)

This is my `unocss.config.ts`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  shortcuts: [
    {...},
  ],
  rules: [],
  theme: {
    colors: {...},
    screens: {
      md: {'max': '1800px'}
    },
    breakpoints: {
      md: {'max': '1800px'}
    },
  },
  presets: [
    presetUno(),
    presetAttributify(),
    presetIcons({
      scale: 1.2,
    }),
  ],
});
```

I want to set `max-width` to replace the default `min-width`, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**
You must use `lt-` wherever you need to apply *less then* `breakpoint`.

**Long answer:**
Your config is still the same. You may want to change actual `px` value, tho.
So if `md` is 1800px than you may use it as 1800px(included) and more
OR
you may use the same 'md' as 1800px(not included) and less (better set to 1800.1px instead).

```
theme: {
  breakpoints: {
    md: '1800.1px',
  },
}
```

Then to apply styles at this breakpoint (i.e. 1800px) you should write next:

```
/* md => md and more; lt-md => less than md (not equal) */
@screen lt-md {<your stiles>}
```

additional info: https://unocss.dev/presets/wind

Applying inline styles you should follow this:

```
<div styles="<md:color-green400">
```

additional info: https://windicss.org/utilities/general/variants.html

Comment: for inline styles: it was working this way in v0.51.12. Could be changed